# is it possible to force input type="password" to be treated as type="text"?

Tags: security, passwords

When I'm visiting a webpage with password fields, I want to make the password field visible. I'm looking at somebody else's page, so I can't (e.g.) change the type= attribute of the input field, nor can I insert javascript into the page (to do the same thing).

Can I somehow override the -webkit-text-security attribute to force the field to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are thinking what I think you are...

Simply right click on the password field and select inspect element. Change `input type="password"` to `input type="text"`, and whatever you typed in the password field (which was displayed as hidden characters) is then displayed as plain text.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.